# Dynamic setInterval in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

I am going to setup a timer for different events dynamically in HTML.
There is a function to generate an HTML elements when ajax completed as below:

```
function buildOnlineQuizIns(courseId, onlineQuizes) {
var items = '';
var d = new Date();
var timeStamp = d.getTime();
$.each(onlineQuizes, function (key, value) {
    var date1 = new Date(value['startDate']);
    var t1 = date1.getTime()+value['offsetTime']*60*1000;
    var date2 = new Date(value['endDate']);
    var t2 = date2.getTime()+value['offsetTime']*60*1000;

    var startDate = convertDate(value['startDate'], value['offsetTime']);
    var endDate = convertDate(value['endDate'], value['offsetTime']);
    items += '<table id="quizOnlineItem'+value['qsClassId']+'" class="quizOnlineItem">' +
            '<tr><td style="color: #0000cb; font-weight: bold; width: 70px;">Quiz Set:</td><td style="margin-left: 10px;">'+value['name']+'</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td style="margin-right: 10px; color: #0000cb; font-weight: bold;">Header:</td><td>' + value['quizHeader'] + '</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td style="margin-right: 10px; color: #00B300; font-weight: bold;">Start Date:</td><td>' + startDate + '</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td style="margin-right: 10px; color: #DB3315; font-weight: bold;">End Date:</td><td>' + endDate + '</td></tr>' +
        '</table>' +
        '<div id="countdown'+value['qsId']+'" class="timer">test</div>';
    var timeLeft = '';
    if(timeStamp<t1){
        seconds[value['qsId']] = t1 - timeStamp;
        countdownTimer[value['qsId']] = setInterval(timer(value['qsId']), 1000);
    }else if(timeStamp>t1 && timeStamp<t2){
        seconds[value['qsId']] = t2 - timeStamp;
        countdownTimer[value['qsId']] = setInterval(timer(value['qsId']), 1000);
    }
});
return items;
```

}

and there is a function for timer as below:

```
var countdownTimer = [];
var seconds = [];
function timer(qsId) {
    alert(countdownTimer[qsId]);
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds[qsId]/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds[qsId]) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds[qsId] % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
    }
    $('#countdown'+qsId).html(days + "day " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds);
    if (seconds[qsId] == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer[qsId]);
        $('#countdown'+qsId).html("Completed");
    } else {
        seconds[qsId]--;
    }
}
```

However, nothing updates when page loaded. Anyone can help me in this matter please. Thanks!!!

Comment: Could you either debug it yourself, or post the whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a function to setInterval, you must pass the function without calling it:

This call the function when this line is executed:

```
setInterval(timer(value['qsId']), 1000);
```

This call the function only after 1s:

```
setInterval(function() {
    timer(value['qsId'])
}, 1000);
```

Ps: Didn't check if this was the problem, but I think it will be a problem anyways.

Comment: Thanks Matheus. The timer is working very well. But when counting down days it is more than 2000 days. Something went wrong here.